# most *efficient* way to populate select with Jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, select, performance

I have several selects that I populate using JQuery Ajax. Most load fine. There are one or two of these queries however, that in a few rare cases return a LOT of records to the select. I was wondering if the way that I am populating the selects is the most efficient way to do so from client side code.

I omitted some stuff to make the code a litle shorter.

```
$(function () {
    FillAwcDll()
});
function FillAwcDll() {
FillSelect('poleDdl', 'WebService.asmx/Pole', params, false, null, false);
}

function ServiceCall(method, parameters, onSucess, onFailure) {
    var parms = "{" + (($.isArray(parameters)) ? parameters.join(',') : parameters) + "}"; // to json
    var timer = setTimeout(tooLong, 100000);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: appRoot + "/services/" + method,
        data: parms,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
            alert("success");
            if (typeof onSucess == 'function' || typeof onSucess == 'object')
                onSucess(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (msg, err) {

            }
        }
    });

function FillSelect(sel, service, param, hasValue, prompt, propCase) {
    var selectId = 'select#{0}'.format(sel);
    if ($(selectId) == null) {
        alert('Invalid FillSelect ID');
        return;
    }
    $(selectId + ' option').remove();
    $('<option class=\'loading\' value=\'\'>loading...</option>').appendTo(selectId);
    ServiceCall(service,
                param,
                function (data, args) {
                    $(selectId + ' option').remove();

                    if (prompt != null && prompt.length > 0) {
                        $('<option class=\'selectPrompt\' value=\'\' selected>{0}</option>'.format(prompt)).appendTo(selectId);
                    }
                    $.each(data, (hasValue)
                        ? function (i, v) {
                            $('<option value=\'{0}\'>{1}</option>'.format(v.Key, (propCase) ? v.Value.toProperCase() : v.Value)).appendTo(selectId);
                        }
                        : function (i, v) {
                            $('<option value=\'{0}\'>{1}</option>'.format(v, (propCase) ? v.toProperCase() : v)).appendTo(selectId);
                        })

                },
                FailedServiceCall);
                }

String.prototype.format = function () {
    var pattern = /\{\d+\}/g;
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(pattern, function (capture) { return args[capture.match(/\d+/)]; });
}
```

So this just loops around and fills the selects. Is there a better way to do this? Note the alert("success") line fire almost immediately, so the data is coming back fast, but then after that it hangs trying to fill the select.

UPDATE: (3) this is working really well. Although there is some issue. I have onBlur(call function to reload selects) and when the onBlur is activated and the selects re-load, the page just takes FOREVER to load, so long I has to stop it... not sure why?

```
    ServiceCall(service,
            param,
            function (data, args) {
                var $select = $(selectId);
                var vSelect = '';
                if (prompt != null && prompt.length > 0) {
                    vSelect += '<option class=\'selectPrompt\' value=\'\' selected>{0}</option>'.format(prompt);
                }
                if (hasValue) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        vSelect += '<option value=\'{0}\'>{1}</option>'.format(v.Key, (propCase) ? v.Value.toProperCase() : v.Value);
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        vSelect += '<option value=\'{0}\'>{1}</option>'.format(v, (propCase) ? v.toProperCase() : v);
                    });
                }
                $select.html(vSelect);
                delete vSelect;
                delete data;
            },
            FailedServiceCall);
}
```

Comment: @kralco, is it an option to have the returned data formatted as `val:text` one per line ?

Comment: or `val:text`<tab>`val:text` ..

Comment: @kralco, in your updated example your are adding the whole data in each `option +=` not just the relevant item from the loop..

Comment: i can format it however is going to get me the speed i need

Comment: that was my try before I used your solution. I'll put what i have now, it's pretty much exactly what you put in your answer

Comment: @Gaby - I could return it form the database like that, or I could do the formatting on the webservice, that way there is no processing on the client side, just return a huge html string of <option>data1</option><option>....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried creating a jquery object in memory and populating that, and at the end putting it in the DOM?

like this

```
var vSelect = $('<select/>'); // our virtual select element
```

and in the `each` method use that to append the `options`

```
vSelect.append('<option>..</option>');
```

and at the end append in the DOM the virtual object's html

```
$(selectId).html( vSelect.html() );
```

---

something else that would speed your current code is to keep a reference to the `select` element (*instead of its id*) and append to it directly instead of having jquery find the element in each appending (*as you do now*)

---

**Update with full code**

replace the part inside FilLSelect

```
ServiceCall(service,
            param,
            <SNIP>...<SNIP>,
            FailedServiceCall);
            }
```

with

```
ServiceCall(service,
            param,
            function (data, args) {
                var $select = $(selectId);
                var vSelect = '';
                if (prompt != null && prompt.length > 0) {
                     vSelect += '<option class=\'selectPrompt\' value=\'\' selected>{0}</option>'.format(prompt);
                }
                if (hasValue)
                {
                   $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        vSelect += '<option value=\'{0}\'>{1}</option>'.format(v.Key, (propCase) ? v.Value.toProperCase() : v.Value);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                   $.each(data,function (i, v) {
                        vSelect += '<option value=\'{0}\'>{1}</option>'.format(v, (propCase) ? v.toProperCase() : v);
                    });
                }
                 $select.html( vSelect );

            },
            FailedServiceCall);
            }
```

if you page can bring back the whole data as a string in the format of

`option_value:option_text<TAB>option_value:option_text<TAB>option_value:option_text...` then you could do a replace with a regular expression and just put it in the select element.

```
var options = data.replace( /([\S ]+)(?=:)(:)([\S ]+)/gi, '<option value="$1">$3</option>');
$(selectID).empty().append(options);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on how I would put this code into the current code I have. I'm not very familiar with how the original code actually works.

Comment: your awesome! this works in about 10 seconds, which is a lot better than, well, i let it run for about 20 minutes in my original solution and it was only about half way through the values! Thanks so much! Suppose it would be greedy to ask if there was any way to make it even more efficient? anything else that's going on that could be tweaked?

Comment: so your solution essentially creates a string that has the html for the select. Think I could maybe do the same thing on the database side an just return the whole html in one database string? think that would be more efficient? or is that just a ridiculous way to return data from a database?

Comment: @kralco, well one way would be to, as you say, return the data ready to be included in the `select` element directly, but you would have to replicate your *properCase* server-side. The possible issue here would be the increase in data transferred. You will have to benchmark to see.. Also your returned data will only useful in this specific scenario.. So if you used them in other places with different results you would have to make a different page to return those..

Comment: ya. something odd is going on, because if I apply a autoPostBack = true to one of the selects and select an option the page just freezes... I'm thinking maybe its running out of memory? idk... once I select an option, the selects should contain a lot less data, so it should be faster to load them...

Comment: @kralco, added some more info down at the bottom, for a one-off replacement of text using regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic one where msg is your JSON data object returned from the server.

```
var options = "";

$(msg).each(function() {
   options += $('<option />').val(yourValue).text(yourDisplayValue);
});


$(selectID).empty().append(options);
```

Personally, I prefer using a templating system to insert html from javascript.  I use [Microsoft's jQuery Templates](https://github.com/nje/jquery-tmpl).  The syntax for that would be simple:

```
var options = $.tmpl("<option value="${yourValue}">${yourDisplayValue}</option>", msg);

$(selectID).empty().append(options);
```

The choice is yours.  :)

Comment: ok. I figured it out. Its defiantly better. (see edit to question) but still too slow. Any ideas to make it faster? Not sure what it going on but it just took 3.5 minutes to complete, and nothing was in the select box when it was done.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary container that is not attached to the dom.
After filling the container with the options attach all children to the select.

```
var temp = $('<select></select>');
$('<option></option>').attr('value', 1).text('First').appendTo(temp);
$(selectId).children().remove();
temp.children().detach().appendTo($(selectId));
```

Maybe this will work too:

```
$(selectId).html(temp.html());
```